# numberofRowsinSection can it return the VALUES of NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is that possible to return as number of rows in section the **value**(and not the count) of an NSMutableArray

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of rows in section: %@",[arrayofNombre objectAtIndex:section]);//it prints the right value
    return [arrayofNombre objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

The application just crashes, and when I put a constant value (return 2 for example), the application runs but it gives not the expected result.
I'm surely missing something.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you're returning an NSNumber, while the method is expecting an NSInteger. You should convert the NSNumber as follows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of rows in section: %@",[arrayofNombre objectAtIndex:section]);//it prints the right value
    return [[arrayofNombre objectAtIndex:section] intValue];
}
```

Comment: How can you detect the problems :D ! It solved my problem :). Thank you very much, and accepted.

Comment: You're welcome, just a wild guess considering that an NSArray can only hold NSNumbers! :)

Answer (score 1):

No. You are returning an NSInteger. You need to explicitly declare a property to hold the value if you choose.

Answer (score 1):

If your array holds instances of NSNumber you need to convert the object to NSInteger:

```
return [[arrayofNombre objectAtIndex:section] integerValue];
```